# How do I get JUnit XML output from Jest?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jestjs

I have a React app that has Jest tests.  I'm configuring Jest in my `package.json`:

```
…
  "jest": {
    "setupEnvScriptFile": "./test/jestenv.js",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/setup-jasmine-env.js",
    "testRunner": "node_modules/jest-cli/src/testRunners/jasmine/jasmine2.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules/q",
      "./node_modules/react"
    ]
  },
…
```

The `setup-jasmine-env.js` looks like this:

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.VERBOSE = true;
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
  new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: "output/",
    filePrefix: "test-results"
  })
);
```

It took a bit of working to get that jasmine env setup correctly, but I"m not seeing anything in the `output` directory (indeed, it isn't created and creating it myself doesn't help).  I suspect that my alterations to the `jasmine` var aren't the same one that Jest is using, but I can't figure out how to hook them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like all you're missing from the above setup is to add `jasmine-reporters` to `unmockedModulePathPatterns`, so give the following a go:

```
"jest": {

   ...

   "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
     "./node_modules/q",
     "./node_modules/react",
     "./node_modules/jasmine-reporters"
   ]
},
```

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE:** for anyone else experiencing this problem, I have put a working demo up [here](https://github.com/JoeDevine/jest-jasmine-reporters-example).

Comment: Exactly correct—`"./node_modules/jasmine-reporters"` needs to be in the `unmockedModulePathpatterns`

Comment: Unfortunately, this only reports for a single suite's test results. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/104#issuecomment-233201678 for the discussion and solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you use a more recent version of jest (I'm looking at 16.0.2), you don't need to specify the `testrunner` because jasmine is the default. You also don't need the `unmockedModulePathPatterns` section of the jest config.

I.e. you just need to include the following `devDependencies` in your `package.json`:

```
"jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
"jest": "^16.0.2",
"jest-cli": "^16.0.2"
```

And add this jest config to your `package.json` (note: you no longer need the `unmockedModulePathPatterns` section):

```
"jest": {
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setup-jasmine-env.js"
}
```

And then use Drew's `setup-jasmine-env.js` from the question.

Comment: This worked for me; thank you. I did, however, have to use `"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setup-jasmine-env.js"` for jest to locate the module.

Answer (score 5):

Jest has support for its own reporters via the testResultsProcessor config. So I wrote up a little thing that generates compatible junit xml for this. You can find it here. https://github.com/palmerj3/jest-junit

Comment: The repo mentioned in this link is a fork.. 
Here is the link to the original repo : https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit